# How do I use preg_replace in PHP with {{ mustache }}

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to replace all the occurrences of {{key}} in one string with it's corresponding key in array (or stdClass)

I am not quite sure how do I build the regex properly.

For example:

I would want to make this string:

```
"Hi my name is {{name}}, I am {{age}} years old."
```

And this array:

```
$person = [
    "name" => "John",
    "age" => 28,
    "city" => "London",
    "country" => "England",
];
```

To this:

```
"Hi my name is John, I am 28 years old."
```

I thought about using `str_replace` but that means that if  I have 10k keys on a potential person it would iterate 10k times, while in `preg_replace` I just replace two times. So using `str_replace` is **NOT** an option due to bad efficiency.

I also know how the proper regex, but this has potentially unlimited $i where $i is the index of the found match, and I am not sure how to do that as well.

What is the proper pattern to do that and the proper replacement?

Comment: Can you share what you've tried? Your array has some syntax errors

Comment: `$person` "array" isn't `php`, once you fix it, you can use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Comment: I said stdClass

Comment: Changed to array for people who are having hard time reading.

Comment: @JacobCohen I resemble that remark [blush]. I'm really just here for the [tag:regex] my [tag:php] is just passable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you're going to want to properly define an [`array`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

```
$person = [
     'name' =>'John',
     'age' => '28',
     'city' => 'London',
     'country' => 'England'
];
```

If you're going to use `preg_replace`, ["Now you have 2 problems."](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/223634/98845) So why not instead just use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) in a loop. For example say your input is: `$string = "Hi my name is {{name}}, I am {{age}} years old."` You could do:

```
while($i = current($person)) {
    $string = str_replace('{{'.key($person).'}}', $i, $string);
    next($person);
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/WicFjK)

**EDIT:**

If you've deemed that the number of entries in `$person` justifies the use of a regex then you'll need to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) rather than `preg_replace`, so you can index into your `array`:

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('/{{((?:[^}]|}[^}])+)}}/', function($match) use ($person) { return ($person[$match[1]]); }, $string);
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/fKh7Md)

---

Since you're using regexes anyway you can get the additional capabilities of handling escaped characters. If you're interested in that you would need to use a regex like:

```
\G(?:[^{\\]|\\.|{[^{])*{{((?:[^}\\]|\\.|}[^}])+)}}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/x2B0CV/1)

And you'll need to adjust your `preg_replace_callback` to:

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('/\G((?:[^{\\]|\\.|{[^{])*){{((?:[^}\\]|\\.|}[^}])+)}}/', function($match) use ($person) { return $match[1].$person[$match[2]]; }, $string);
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/MVsbSb)

Comment: I do not want to run on ALL my `$person` keys, it might be a lot higher than a few in the string and it is not efficient.

Comment: @JacobCohen Understanding this I like your question a bit more, +1. I'm not aware of a way to use `preg_replace` to do `array` interpolation inline. I believe your best bet is `preg_replace_callback`. I've updated my answer accordingly.